# How to check from a child form if another form is running in it's MDI parent?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a MDI form. I want to check within a running child of this form if another form is running. Something like:

```
    if (this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.Contains(MyForm2))
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
```

Where `MyForm2` is the name (class name) for the form I am looking for. The compiler says something like "Class name is not valid at this point".

How to do this properly? Please note that I can have multiple instances of "MyForm2" running at that momemnt (Well, with different instance names!)

Comment: If multiple instances of `MyForm2` exist, do you want to do something with each of them?  Or do you just need to know if ANY `MyForm2` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a loop to cycle through the MdiChildren collection to see if any form of the specified Type exists. Contains requires a specific instance to return valid data:

```
        foreach (var form in this.MdiParent.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (form is MyForm2)
            {
                // Do something. 

                // If you only want to see if one instance of the form is running,
                // add a break after doing something.

                // If you want to do something with each instance of the form, 
                // just keep doing something in this loop.
            }
        }
```

Comment: @ScottRippey: yep, this code accounts for that quite nicely since MyForm2 is the name of the class.

Comment: This code will run multiple times for each form ... I believe that the OP only wants to know if `MyForm2` exists, and wants to "Do Something" once.  So I'd recommend adding a `break;` or something.

Comment: @ScottRippey: The OP didn't make it clear in the question as to the intent of searching for the form. It could be that they want to gather values from each instance or they just want to know if any instance of the form is open. I have added comments to the answer to reflect the ambiguity and provide direction for either scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the type of each child.

For example you can use the `is` keyword ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) to determine if a child is the correct type:

```
if (this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.Any(child => child is MyForm2))
{
}
```

The `.Any()` method requires a reference to `System.Linq`.  [Read more about Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech Or `MdiChildren.OfType<MyForm2>().Any()` ... but my original way is definitely the most readable.

Comment: Quibbling: this isn't selective enough.  It also finds any forms that are derived from MyForm2.  Consider child.GetType() == typeof(MyForm2).

Comment: @HansPassant That's a good point, but it is hard to judge by the OP if he cares about inheritance ... I assumed he doesn't.